# How to club the orders in such a way that maximum number of items are common amongst them?

Tags: python, r, data-mining, clustering, data

Consider the following data set:
The above table shows the quantity of each item used in the orders SO1 SO2 etc. I need to club the orders in such a way that maximum number of items are common amongst them.
For example:

[image: data]

SO1 SO3 SO5  can be clubbed for 8 items ( Item 1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11) and SO2 and SO4 can clubbed together because 9 items are common ( Item 1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11).

The approach I followed was:
 I found out the number of combinations possible as in (SO1 SO2), (SO1 SO3), (SO1 SO4)……(SO1 SO2 SO3), (SO1 SO2 SO4),….(SO1 SO2 SO3 SO4),…(SO1 SO2 SO3 SO4 SO5). For n number of SOs I would be getting around 2^n -n -1 combinations. 
Later I compared the data in each combination for equality.

Based on the number of matches, I thought I would be able to select the combinations. But this process would become cumbersome for 300 shop orders with around 2000 items. And it is taking a lot of time to compute as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using **frequent itemset mining**?

It finds the most frequent item combinations.

The key idea is that when item A is not frequent, you don't need to further explore any combinations including A.

Comment: In frequent itemset mining it only cares about whether the item is present or not in the order.It does not consider the quantitiy of the item needed.

Comment: Not have you explained if it matters, and how it should be taken into account. There *are* ways to enhance FIM with quantity information - it's usually just so expensive that you'd rather analyze this in postprocessing.